# check if a url has anything after the domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net

im using asp.net c#.

I want to check if the current url has anything after the domain name.

e.g if the current url

www.example.com/

or

www.example.com

i want to set a bool to true.
if it has anything after i want to set it to false. e.g.

www.example.com/stuff

how can i do this?

should return false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
bool isRoot = new Uri("http://www.example.com").AbsolutePath == "/";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [System.Uri.PathAndQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery(v=VS.100).aspx) to check this. PathAndQuery should be empty/null for your first case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expressions on that...

Use:

(((http|https)://)|(www.))+(([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})|([0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}))?

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I believe that even if you hit the domain directly at www.example.com, ASP.NET is going to detect the URL including the default page, which is commonly default.aspx.

Simply check for something like

```
string defaultPage = "/default.aspx";
return Request.Url.PathAndQuery == defaultPage;
```